# Wifi networks not discovered in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04. I have a USB type WiFi adaptor to connect to a wireless network, but on enabling the WiFi I do not see any network available to connect with. I have tried the available methods already, but it didn't work. On removing WiFi adaptor the WiFi option disappears from menu, so I am assuming the system is detecting the WiFi adaptor but showing no network to connect.

Wifi adaptor:

[image]

No wifi option on removing adaptor:

[image]

After adding wifi adaptor to the usb port:

[image]

Output of `lsusb` :

```
kumar@LianLi:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 258a:0049 BY Tech Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 26ce:01a2 ASRock LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you give us the name of the Wi-Fi adaptor? And can you add the output of `lsusb`(you'll need to write this into a terminal. you can open a terminal from the applications menu). And if you can spot which one is the Wi-Fi adaptor, can you add the output of "lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY" where XXX is the Bus number, and YYY is the device number written on the same line with the Wi-Fi adapter. If you can't find it just add the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Thanks for your time in trying to help me . As i was not able to attach the output here so i have attached it in the question itself . Regarding the make of adaptor I was not able to find it as it only has written 802.11n on top of it and as I was not sure which one is the adaptor I attached the complete output . Hope it helps in understanding the issue .

Comment: It seems as your Wi-Fi adapter is Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter, so the necessary numbers would be 001 and 002. So the second command would be `lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/002`. I assume that you have the Wi-Fi adapter still on the same USB port on your computer, if you plugged your Wi-Fi adapter on an other USB port you'll need to adjust the numbers accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your Wi-Fi adapter need an additional [driver](https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu).

In order to install the driver you'll need to enter these commands sequentially on a terminal. As these command require `sudo` privileges, you'll need to enter your user's password when asked. (For security, no characters will be shown when entering a password. After you've typed your password, press `Enter` and the command will do it's job.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install rtl8188fu-dkms
```

Comment: "can't put the interface output here as it is quite long" Please put the output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I still have submitted the output which is accessible by here -https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t4hV3ZFRkd/ . So , the steps that i followed after running above three commands are as : After downloading those drivers i opened the folder and opened readme file and found out these drivers have some issue with kernel 5.15 ( my current kernel) . So , i followed the instructions given the file and at the end when I checked for one last time I found my issue was solved . Hats off to the hard working and dedicated members for helping us selflessly  .

Comment: Will the solution work if my wifi-adapter is different, say, rtl810xe?

Comment: It says that it is unable to locate package rtl810xe-dkms.

Comment: @mandudeman Please start your own new question.